# is partial update a cpu intensive task in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, cpu-usage

I have a document type which at the time of getting Indexed has close to 60 fields. I do search, index and update operations on these documents.

My CPU consumption was just over 40 percent average before introducing one new change.

Recently i introduced a change, which at times i will be updating the indexed documents with 60 more new fields. So now in a whole 120 fields. With this new change i doubled the number of fields getting stored in each document.

**Api**:
/_update/docId?retry_on_conflict=2

**Payload**:
{"doc":{ "key61": "value61" , ... , "key120", "value120" }}

With this change my cpu usage is spiking over 75 percent.

Can someone help me understand what is causing this cpu spike?

Answer (score 1):

I think culprit is update request, as it does extra computing of retrieving the document which needs to be updated, add/remove additional fields according to your update request and then again index the updated document.

This requires also the serializing/de-serializing the whole content which is costly espically when you have large number of fields and text content.

If instead of updating, you can send all 120 fields and use index operation IMO it will be much faster and you can benchmark it.

Comment: Hi @Amit. Thank you for taking time to reply. I will try this and update whether it helped. Thanks again.

Comment: @KarthikeyanAmaresan looking forward to hear the update from u

Comment: @KarthikeyanAmaresan did you get a time to validate it ?

Comment: Hi @Amit, I am working on it, Please give a couple more days to validate it. I will definitely get back on the findings.

Comment: @KarthikeyanAmaresan its been long time, just wanted to follow up on it to get some update from you, it would be great if you can provide some update so that we don't loose the track of it

Comment: Hi @Amit Even after stopped partial updating the extra fields, instead reindexing the whole document also didn't help brining down the cpu usage. And also queries are so slow, and thread pools limits are maxing out causing subsequent requests to reject out.

Comment: @KarthikeyanAmaresan looks like your cluster and indices are not well designed

Comment: @KarthikeyanAmaresan its been really long, would be great if you can provide the update